# HttpUrlConnection fatal error

Tags: java, android, http

I have problem with Android using the class HttpUrlConnection my method is this:

```
public InputStream test() {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStream in= null;

       try {
         in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
       }catch(IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
        finally {
         urlConnection.disconnect();
       }
return in;
}
```

When i execute this method android generates this exception:

> 05-03 15:15:19.116: W/System.err(1085): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   05-03 15:15:19.116: W/System.err(1085):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>   05-03 15:15:19.116: W/System.err(1085):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
>   05-03 15:15:19.116: W/System.err(1085):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
>   05-03 15:15:19.116: W/System.err(1085):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:71)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
>   05-03 15:15:19.126: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at com.BertacchiMazzoni.HTTPClient.HttpClientTutorial.test(HttpClientTutorial.java:35)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at com.BertacchiMazzoni.HTTPClient.HTTPClientActivity.onCreate(HTTPClientActivity.java:18)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
>   05-03 15:15:19.136: W/System.err(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   05-03 15:15:19.146: W/System.err(1085):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-03 15:15:19.146: W/System.err(1085):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-03 15:15:19.146: W/System.err(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   05-03 15:15:19.146: W/System.err(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-03 15:15:19.146: W/System.err(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-03 15:15:19.146: W/System.err(1085):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   05-03 15:15:19.146: W/System.err(1085):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   05-03 15:15:19.146: W/System.err(1085):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Can i resolve this problem? Where is the error?

Thanks a lot!
Regards!

Comment: have u given INTERNET permission in manifeast file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google for the exception leads you here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Which states:

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

So basically I'm guessing you're performing your network operation on the main application thread; and for Honeycomb and up it looks like you can't do this. It's a bad idea anyway, as it's likely to make your application hang and appear unresponsive. You'd need to use another thread or handler or asynctask or Loader to perform the operation.

Answer (score 2):

Move your code to the Background Thread.

```
new Thread(){
     public void run(){
          test();
     }
}.start();
```

We can not access the network in the Main UI Thread when the os version is ICS, It protect that your application will not block The UI when do a long-duration operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your log says that "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". It means that you're trying to run this network code on the main thread, which is not a great thing to do, since network access tends to block for quite long periods of time. So newer Android version have a protection against this, and prevent you from doing so.

To solve it, run this code in another thread. Use an AsyncTask or plain java thread for example.